# Strange files in Wordpress uploads directory

Tags: wordpress, server, hosting

Recently I've checked there are many strange files (containing some HTML/Javascript code) in my WP website's uploads directory. If someone has any idea about how they are created and how can I remove them so that they will not re appear. attached is the screenshot of one of my directory containing those files:

[image]

Comment: just looking at the name of file we can't guess what they contain. open one of them with editor and provide code of them to us. it may be generated with some plugin, code, or maybe some malware

Comment: It contains following code:

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan - It contains following code: https://justpaste.it/1gjgf

Comment: Most of them seems to be youtube links, but why those are created files in wp/uploads folder? also there are bootstrap.swf which contains: https://justpaste.it/1gjh6

Comment: its going to have about 10 year age. do you have that youtube videos in the website?

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan - Yes those are there on the website.

Comment: I see. do you use some plugin for it?